# what time zone does Civi think its in?

Tags: scheduled-job

I am trying to send a scheduled mailer and need to know what time CIVI believes it is in ?
Right now CIVI appears to be 2 hrs. ahead of my time zone but there is not indication of time zone anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: there is a tag for timezone and you may find an answer already in those, and if not then worth adding that tag to your question. https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timezone

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE. As far as I know, the timezone is just inherited from the host CMS. I did not have to select any on install and I can change it in the CMS (WordPress in my case). So check what time the CMS believes it to be in.